# SSH keys don't work on KDE

Tags: ssh, kde

I've got my ssh keys working on Gnome and XFCE (using gnome-keyring).

However when I switched to KDE, then it doesn't work at all.

What's more, even when I start ssh-agent, and add keys, and try to connect to a server, then it looks like my keys are being checked, but are not used, and as a result I'm being asked for a password.

How can I simply use ssh keys on KDE?

Comment: This a strange behavior, I use ssh keys under KDE without problems. Use the -v option to ssh to see what's going on.